# Show that the covariance is also $\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) = E[(X-E(X))Y] = E[X(Y-E(Y))]$

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

The covariance between $X$ and $Y$ is given by $cov(X, Y) = E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))]$. However, I was told that an equivalent expression for covariance is $$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) = E[(X-E(X))Y] = E[X(Y-E(Y))]$$ Why is this true? Isn't the expressions only true for when $E(Y) = 0$ or $E(X) = 0$?

Comment: Don't we have $cov(X, Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. And we have, $E[(X-E(X))Y] = E[XY-E(X)Y] = E[XY] -E[E(X)Y]= E[XY] - E(X)E(Y)$? So they are equivalent?

Comment: @elbarto Yes, that is another proof....

Comment: @GrahamKemp Hmmm... $\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) = E[(X-E(X))Y] = E[X(Y-E(Y))]$ seems impeccable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $E(E(X)(Y-E(Y))=E(X)E(Y-E(Y))=0$

Hence,
$E(X(Y-E(Y))=E(X(Y-E(Y))+E(X)E((Y-E(Y))=E(X(Y-E(Y))+E(E(X)(Y-E(Y))$

And use the linearity of the expectation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand another way of proving it!